# Seaborn graph where indices are on x-axis and DataFrame values are on y-axis

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to plot a DataFrame and am unable to get exactly what I'm looking for. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'Jim': {'ball': 5, 'bat': 8}, 'Nancy': {'ball': 9, 'bat': 10}}).T
```

I would like a graph where Jim and Nancy are on the x-axis and the y-axis is the values 1-10. I would like the points to have two colors - one for the bat data and one for the ball data, with a legend explaining this. I am able to get close with the following:

```
for _, series in df.iteritems():
    sns.scatterplot(x=df.index, y=series)
```

But this seems wrong, labels the y-axis as `ball`, and doesn't show a legend. I think closer to what I want is `sns.scatterplot(x=df.index, y=df, hue=df.columns)` but this gives the following error: `ValueError: Data must be 1-dimensional`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this plot?

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df)
```

[image]